# Issue with ApexCharts in Next.js 14 - ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: next.js, react-apexcharts

I'm encountering an issue while trying to use ApexCharts in a Next.js 14 project. When I run the project, I receive the following error in the terminal:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3o5p.png)

It seems to be related to the usage of the window object. Has anyone else faced this problem, especially with Next.js 14? How did you resolve it?

I've attempted a few approaches to resolve this issue, Despite these effort the issue persists. I was expecting that these adjustments would resolve the ReferenceError: window is not defined problem during rendering.